# Soot on the fuse when changed

Tags: circuit-breaker

A couple days ago, our water pump conked out.  My brother had to change the fuse to get it running again.  He said there was soot (or something like it) around the fuse when he swapped it out.  It was the same as a conking out a couple months ago.

Where is this ash coming from?  Is the fuse box about to catastrophically fail?  It's the same box from when the house was built around 1956.  Just over a decade ago, the power company messed up fixing a line and a quarter of our stuff got burnt out from the surge and they suggested replacing the whole system coming into our house (i.e. the junction box), which we still haven't done.  (Since that equipment is on our property, they weren't going to pay for it, although it's their fault.)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably carbon from burnt plastic (maybe from wire insulation... so charred cloth if the wires are 60 years old). A picture might be helpful.

Comment: If the fuse contact points are loose there may be some arcing causing heat and soot. How old is the pump it may be drawing more now as getting close to end of life. The problem 10 years ago probably has nothing to do with this problem.